# JMeter - Use a test fragment from another .jmx

Tags: jmeter

in my project I need to have a jmx (let's call it main.jmx) script that will have a bunch of TestFragments (of which each of them will be a UserJourney composed by multiple requests and "flows") and I want to have other jmx files that might point to some of the test fragments of the main.jmx to use only some of them. I know that there is the **IncluderController** but if I am not wrong, it does not allow me to execute parts from other script but the script as a whole.

The idea is to have a single jmx (main.jmx) that would "store" all the UserJourneys and have other multiple jmxs that would be able to call some UJs from the main script.

Is there a way to have something that allow me to do the job without needing to create a jmx for each UserJourney and set them in multiple IncluderControllers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a proper Single Test Plan in place.

(UserJourney.jmx)

```
Test Plan
 -Thread Group
  -Transaction Controller#1 (main)
    -Data sampler (jdbc etc)
    -Request Sampler / TestFragments
      -Response Extraction(json extractor/regular exp extractor)

  -Transaction Controller#2 (UserJourney)
    -Request Sampler / UserJourney (takes response from main controller as request params)
  -Listeners
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Yugal, but the idea is to have a single jmx (main.jmx) that would "store" all the UserJourneys and have other multiple jmxs that would be able to call some UJs from the main script.